# Вхождение в область

Tags: c++, геометрия

Здраствйте.Не могу найти свою ошибку ,не проходит седьмой, скрытый тест. задача из степика.

> Напишите программу, при выполнении которой с клавиатуры считываются координаты точки на плоскости (x , y - действительные числа) и определяется принадлежность этой точки заданной заштрихованной области (включая границы). В случае, если точка внутри заштрихованной области -- выведите слово "Inside", если снаружи - "Outside".

ниже мой код. 2е касательные я ограничиваю условиями . а паралельную прямую неравествами X и Y.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  double   x , y;
  cin >> x >> y;
  if(y <= x + 6 && y  <= -x  - 1 && (y  <= -0.5 && y >= -4  && x <= 1 && y >= -6)) {
    cout << "Inside";
  }else{
    cout << "Outside";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вашему условию, удовлетворяет, например, точка (-1, -1)

Comment: надо провести два рандомных луча, и если кол во пересечений четное, то она снаружи, а если  нечетное то внутри

Comment: Извините , но я вас не понимаю.

Comment: для того что бы узнать находится точка внутри или снаружи области нам надо из точки выпустить несколкьо лучей в лсучайных направлениях, и если они будут пересекать контуры фигуры четное кол-во раз, то эта точка  снаружи фигуры, а если нечетное , то внутри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переделал ваше условие проверки:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  double   x , y;
  cin >> x >> y;
  if(y <= -x - 3 && y <= x + 2 && y >= -6) {
    cout << "Inside";
  }else{
    cout << "Outside";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: если можно. дайте коментарии) к своему решению. почему y >= -6 ?

Comment: у нас есть три прямые, каждые задаются своим уравнением(y =-x-3, y = x + 2, y = -6), и каждая прямая делит плоскость на две полуплоскости, поэтому входная точка должна принадлежать каждой полуплоскости. В случае с  _y >= -6_  мы проверяем что точка лежит выше этой прямой